# Waiting for a change in the html using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to have the selenium browser pick up a change in the html of a auction site, and alert me of the problem. The script is looking at number and waiting for it to change. The problem is that is not picking up any changes, even tho there is one.

also: 
Could this be because `WebDriverWait` is waiting for the time to run out before moving on? ex. `90000`

```
browser.get(('https://www.hubzu.com/property/900705469328-7745-SW-86th-St-Unit-D-417-Miami-FL-33143'))# Live Auction Bid URL
time.sleep(2)
propertyaddress = browser.find_element_by_id('streetName')
propertyprice = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('bid-price')
try:                                
    WebDriverWait(browser, 90000).until(  # Change to 90000 seconds
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'bid-price'), r"((?<=\()[0-9]*)")
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two issues.

1. `find_elements_by_class_name('bid-price')` gets the element that contains the element that has the bid price, instead of the element that has the text.
2. Your wait isn't actually waiting for text to change

```
propertyprice = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.current-bid')
currentBidText = propertyprice.text
try:                                
    WebDriverWait(browser, 90000).until_not(  # Change to 90000 seconds
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.current-bid'), currentBidText)
        )
```

Comment: I think your wait was also not actually waiting for text to change. I don't use python and I didn't debug, but try my changes to the wait I just changed. Basically waiting for the text to not equal the current bid